# Connected undirected acyclic graphs versus trees

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, theory

While I'm studying about graph theory with MIT book 'introduction to algorithm', I was referred to some definitions about graphs and trees.

In MIT's Introduction to Algorithm 3rd Edition book, the appendix tree chapter shows me Theorem B.2, "Properties of Free Trees"

> Let G = (V,E) be an undirected graph. The following statements are equivalent.
>
> 1. G is a free tree
>      ...
> 2. G is acyclic, and |E| = |V| - 1.

Is there an example of connected, undirected, acyclic graph which is not a tree?

Theoritically, if there is a undirected acyclic graph which satisfies the condition that |E| =! |V| - 1, would that work as an example?

If there is an example satisfies that condition, can you show me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any connected acyclic graph is a tree. There are several different equivalent definitions of trees:

- They're connected acyclic graphs.
- They're connected graphs with one more node than edge.
- They're minimally-connected graphs (they're connected, but removing any edge disconnects them)
- They're maximally acyclic graphs (they're acyclic, and adding any missing edge creates a cycle)
- They're graphs where any two nodes have exactly one simple path between them.

So no, you can't find a connected acyclic graph that isn't a tree. :-)